# Camel read files from FTP and store in local resources folder

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to build a simple route that reads from a FTP folder, and stores it in a local resources folder. I am able to connect to the FTP endpoint, but nothing happens after that.

To start my program I use: mvn clean compile camel:run

I'm not really sure what I should do next to debug this anymore.

**Terminal output:**

```
INFO | Apache Camel 2.20.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
 INFO | JMX is enabled
 INFO | Type converters loaded (core: 192, classpath: 4)
 INFO | StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
 INFO | Route: route1 started and consuming from: ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx/ftp/xx/xx?password=xxxxxx&username=xx
 INFO | Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
 INFO | Apache Camel 2.20.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.333 seconds
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nettport</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel_download_file_from_ftp_and_get_name_and_content</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>




    <dependencies>
        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>spi-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- //Spring -->

        <!-- FTP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- //FTP -->

        <!-- Quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- //Quartz -->

        <!-- ActiveMq -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-alpha2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- //Logging -->

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Allows the routes to be run via 'mvn camel:run' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**src/main/java/com/nettport/ReceiverRoute.java:**

```
package com.nettport;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ReceiverRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private String receiverFtpEndpoint;

    public void configure() throws Exception {

        // lets shutdown faster in case of in-flight messages stack up
        getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(10);

        from(receiverFtpEndpoint)
        .log("### FTP Receiver Route started and consuming ###")
        .to("file:data/work_in_progress")
        .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete.");
    }


    public void setReceiverFtpEndpoint(String receiverFtpEndpoint) {
        this.receiverFtpEndpoint = receiverFtpEndpoint;
    }
}
```

**META-INF/spring/camel-contxt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


    <bean id="receiverRoute" class="com.nettport.ReceiverRoute">
        <property name="receiverFtpEndpoint" value="ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx/ftp/xx/xx?username=xx&amp;password=xx"/>
    </bean>


    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeBuilder ref="receiverRoute"/>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: Looks OK. Are you sure, there are files in `ftp/xx/xx` and user `xx` have permission to read this folder? You can enable TRACE logging to see, what is happening. The most interresting logs will start with `org.apache.camel.component.file`

Comment: and `camel-ftp2` component is working with path relative to user home, so check this too. Now, you are consuming from folder `HOME_OF_USER_xx/ftp/xx/xx`

Comment: Thanks for the tips Bedia, I can try them and come with a update later.

Comment: So after doing some more testing I found out that if I specify another path it will create that path on the server, so the FTP connection is working. The problem is that its not downloading the files in the FTP folder.

Comment: This should ideally work. Dump some files with some content in the FTP location and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, colleagues. In case if somebody has troubles like `I have set up a simple route that copies the files form FTP to my local disk folder and it does nothing` try the following:

- Make sure you DO NOT have suspicious `WARN` or `ERROR` level messages in your logs.
- Make sure you have specified the `camel-ftp` or `camel-ftp-starter` in your `pom.xml`. I have set up a Spring Boot application and I have the following dependency in my `pom.xml`

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-ftp-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Make sure you have read this documentation:

  - https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/readme.adoc
  - http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html
- Make sure you have setup everything correctly at your FTP server side:

  - You have a correct schema
  - You have set the user and a password up
- Make sure the directory you want to DOWNLOAD the files FROM (from your FTP server) is `NOT EMPTY`

  - In my case (see below) the folder I use to copy the files FROM is `/home/lordnighton`
  - Use the `FileZilla` client to check the state of folder (it also helps you to copy the files to your FTP server)
- Make sure you FTP server is up and running

> Run the commands one by one to spin up an FTP server as a Docker container

```
    $ docker pull stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    $ docker run -e FTP_USER_NAME=lord -e FTP_USER_PASS=nighton -e FTP_USER_HOME=/home/lordnighton  -d --name ftpd_server -p 21:21 -p 30000-30009:30000-30009 -e "PUBLICHOST=localhost" stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    $ ftp ftp://lord:nighton@localhost:21 # check the connection with user/password
```

- Specify the route in your class that extends `RouteBuilder`:

  ```
  from("ftp://lord@localhost:21/home/lordnighton?password=nighton&passiveMode=true")
      .to("file:src/main/resources/data/from-ftp");
  ```
- You can also switch the logging levels of `camel`'s components to `TRACE` to look through more verbose logs:

  ```
  log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.net=TRACE
  log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.component.file=TRACE
  log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.component.ftp=TRACE
  ```
- Sometimes it is helpful to switch the `passiveMode` to `true`:

  ```
  from("ftp://lord@localhost:21/home/lordnighton?password=nighton&passiveMode=true")
  ```
- Sometimes it is also helpful to look into this example -- `https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-ftp`

**Good luck in debugging!**